# Samsung Galaxy S5 media query

Tags: css, media-queries, samsung-mobile

I've done a bit of searching and have tried a few different things, but for the life of me I cannot seem to specifically target the Samsung Galaxy S5. I'm just playing around with a few things while working on a site but nothing I try seems to target the specific device.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
@media only screen
(min-resolution: 144dpi)
and (device-width: 1920px)
and (orientation: landscape) {/*styles here*/}

@media screen
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), 
(min-resolution: 144dpi)
and (device-width: 1920px)
and (orientation: landscape) {/*styles here*/}

@media only screen
    (device-width: 1920px)
    and (orientation: landscape) {/*styles here*/}

@media only screen
(min-device-width: 1080px)
and (max-device-width: 1920px)
and (orientation: landscape) {/*styles here*/}
```

*Note: I've only included "landscape" specific code, but I have tried it without that and with "portrait", but it still doesn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To be able to help, I need to know *why* you want to target it. What is the desired outcome that you need the identification for? Or: what is the practical problem that needs to be solved? Because there may be much easier methods.

Comment: If you have the S5 browse to; http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/css-media-queries/test-features.html - this will give you the specific values that are eluding you.

Comment: @FrankConijn - the site I am currently building has a header image that I would like to swap out to look good on each device. its not imperative to the function of the site, it just will make for a nicer user experience.

Comment: @CaRDiaK - Thanks for the link. I think that will get me headed in a the right direction.

Comment: I have had problems with several S Galaxy models not rendering content when using media queries. I don't know a solution.

Answer (score 6):

```
@media screen and (device-width: 360px) and (device-height: 640px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
```

According to [source](http://cssmediaqueries.com/target/Samsung+Galaxy+S5.html).

Hope it helps.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me...

```
/* Samsung Galaxy S5 Portrait */    
@media screen(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),(min-resolution: 192dpi)and (device-          width: 1440px)and (orientation: portrait){ 
/*Your styles here */
    html{
  display: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using @media screen and (max-width: 680px) and (orientation:landscape) this helped me out alot I also have a samsung galaxy s5