# How can I fix a div's height based on the viewport height?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with the mobile version of my webpage. As you can see with the code below, I have these two divs set up to take up 100% of the viewport height when the webpage loads. It works perfectly on desktop, but on mobile (or at least my phone - I have a Samsung Galaxy S5) the screen appears to jump because Samsung Internet has a menu that collapses when you scroll down a bit. This causes my two divs to automatically fill the newly available viewport space, hence the "jump".

My question is if anyone knows how to lock the two divs to the initial viewport height before it changes?

```
#welcome-section{
    top: 0;
    color: white;
    height: 94vh;
    background-image: var(--stars-background);
    background-size: 1080px 960px;
}
#navbar {
    z-index: 3;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 6vh;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
}
```

Comment: what site carla

Comment: if your talking about your eportfolio for class then  the issue is the line right here. background-size: 1080px 960px; when you set that star background and it goes to responsive you do not have a media query that is reseting it's height.  your media query is based on css of 96 ppi per inch and your phone is a HD device that has more pixels then I can count. It reports as like a 360px though do to how the device handles the HD screen.

Comment: You also have a min width for 768 coded and a max width for 768.

Comment: Yeah, the 768 max-width is my mobile version. Min 768 is for tablets, and the 1024 is for laptops etc.

Comment: Yeah you can't have a min 768 and a max 768 without some other component resulting in true. So like below the and is  like a java &&

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery was the answer!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                var vheight = $(window).innerHeight();
            vheight = vheight * 0.94;
            $("#welcome-section").height(vheight);
        });
```

This function gets the initial viewport height when the webpage loads, and sets my div at 94% of that since I want to include the navbar in the viewport too. Stops all the jumping.

Oh, and for clarity, here's what I meant by the devices viewport changing:
[image]

As you can see, there's a menu on the internet app that affects the viewport size.

[image]

And when you scroll down, the menu collapses which changes the viewport size. And that caused the "jump" I was talking about.

Comment: I won't, haha. Just 12 more hours and then I can accept it!

Comment: You do realize that requires the entire page to load before applying the fix right? That is why we do this with CSS as the dom is loading instead of a heavy hammer after the dom has been built. Your way does work but I challenge you to look at it via  CSS  with #welcome-section { height: .94vh;} using the media breaks below

Answer (score 0):

These are what you need for most HD phones:

`@media (min-width: 480px) and (max-width:767px) {}`

non HD phones:

`@media (max-width: 479px) {}`

Comment: Yeah, I have media queries in my code. It's just phones come in lots of different sizes and that's why I have the 100vh because I want it to fit every phone. It's because of my phone's automatic changeable viewport size, not because of my code

Comment: This is the actual issue  background-size: 1080px 960px;  have a look at the issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23644972/samsung-galaxy-s5-media-query it will show you that your HD device is not a 1:1 ratio so you have to adjust either withe every device specific queries or just use the two i gave ya and   do #welcome-section{ background-size:100% 20%}

Comment: How do I fix it so?

Comment: Because your saying the background size is a set number of pixels wide and tall and not giving the css a media query for that view port is trying to display it all.

Comment: Ah, sorry I didn't notice the edit in the prior comments. Thanks

Comment: haha no worries it is old man lag that is causing the edits to go in slow